# Is the list sorted?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

Is the trade-off between simplicity and performance worth it?

```
def is_sorted(list_):
    """
    Is the list sorted?

    The simpler `list_ == list(sorted(list_))` has
    time complexity O(N log N), this O(n).

    >>> is_sorted([1, 2, 3])
    True
    >>> is_sorted([1, 2, 7, 3])
    False
    """
    return all(curr <= list_[index + 1]
                  for index, curr in enumerate(list_[:-1]))
```

Comment: I think you'd have to be dealing with a lot of large, mostly-already-sorted lists to beat the cost of calling the function and making a copy of the list (the slice, another `O(n)`). You can't determine if it's worth it *a priori*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe interesting, so this function may be slower than the alternative despite the time-complexity... this is what I get when I don't benchmark. :)

Comment: Well, *maybe*. `O(2n)` is still `O(n)`, after all. But there are fixed costs to consider too.

Comment: "pythonic way to check if a list is sorted or not": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755136/pythonic-way-to-check-if-a-list-is-sorted-or-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest way to do this is with `itertools.tee`.  It basically makes an arbitrary number of copies of iterators.  This avoids having to make a copy of the list (which any slice-based approach would do), avoids having to do any math or indexing, and works on arbitrary iterables, not just lists.

```
try:
    itertools.izip as zip
except ImportError:
    pass
from itertools import tee

def issorted(mylist):
    if not mylist:
        return True
    list1, list2 = tee(mylist)  # make two copies of the list's iterator
    next(list2)  # advance one copy one element
    return all(a<=b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Instead of `tee` you could use the builtin `iter` in a similar way: `list2 = iter(mylist); next(list2)`

Comment: Yes, if you are sure you will only ever have certain types.  Assuming the data type isn't really idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 7):

This can be written much more simply with `izip` from `itertools`. This removes having to fiddle with indices that enumerate gives back. Of course, it should probably also have a check for an list of length 0 or 1 as well.

```
return all(x <= y for x, y in izip(list, list[1:]))
```

Edit: The problem with built-in zip for Python 2 is that it will completely construct the list again in memory, which will kill performance for a large list. If you really want code that's portable between both Python 2 and 3, I'd suggest something like:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:
    izip = zip
```

Comment: No need for a special case, it already works for zero and one elements.

Comment: By the way, I would avoid Python-2 only methods, in Python-3: `>>> from itertools import izip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'
` the built-in `zip` seems the only choice.

Comment: You should `islice` as well, to avoid the creation of a list copy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, that'd also be a good idea...